# Why wrap object initialization in a function?

Tags: javascript, api-design

I've seen several APIs that generate objects in the following manner:

```
const newElement = Class.Object(<object> optionsObject)
```

When checking the source code, you find something like:

```
Class.Object = function (options) {
        return new Class.object(options);
    };
```

My question is, why go through the extra step? it looks like a factory pattern, but it doesn't really vary depending on external factors. Wouldn't it be more intuitive to use the `new` keyword yourself when initializing the object? i.e.:

```
const newElement = new Class.Object(<object> optionsObject)
```

Comment: Well, the first benefit is that you *don't* need the `new` keyword to create objects. So, you'll be able to pass the constructor function/method as a callback, for example. `arrayOfOptions.map(Class.Object)` will give you an array of 10 objects, instead of having to make an entirely new function for it `(options) => new Class.Object(options)` which is more verbose for no real benefit. Also, just like the factory method, it gives more flexibility in the future if you want to adjust the implementation. But it's hard to say *exactly* why the designers used this, just guessing.

Comment: This is a pattern that is commonly used when the static method does some asynchronous initialisation or has other side effects (*in addition* to the object construction), I don't see much benefit for pass-through calls.

Comment: Did you mean `new Class(options)`? The function in your example is calling itself, leading to a stack overflow.

Comment: Ah my bad, I meant new Class.options, it seems the uppercase version was reserved for "default behavior". This on itself gives me some extra insight I hadn't even noticed.

Comment: This pattern allows for singletons to be constructed in the same way as "regular" objects. You don't need knowledge about the nature of the constructed object that way. You just always construct the object in the same way. It's basically a layer of abstraction